# The number of solutions of $2^xpx+k=y^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let's consider the family of diophantine equations
$$2^xpx+k=y^2$$
being $p\gt2$ a prime and $k$ a positive integer.
An example is given by the equation
$$2^x\cdot3x+97=y^2$$
that presents, at least, the $4$ following solutions $(x,y)$:
$$(2,11)\;(3,13)\;(4,17)\;(8,79)$$
**Is it possible to find a pair $(p,k)$ that gives, at least, $5$ solutions?**

Many thanks.

Comment: $(1,10)$ is not a solution to the equation you wrote down, but $(8,79)$ is.

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry for the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: How far have you taken your calculations for $3x2^x+97$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Up to $x=10^5$.